# getWindowManager() returns Null?

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception

I've got an Animation class, which i'm calling it from main class when i need to move an image from somewhere to another... But the thing is when i call it, it turns me NullPointerException. Here's my code:

```
public class Animation extends Activity{

ImageView image;
int width;
int fromXDelta;
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = null;

Animation(View main) {
    image = (ImageView) main.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    fromXDelta = image.getLeft();
            // this line gives me error:
    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
}

public void animateToLeft () {      
    translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -fromXDelta, 0, 0);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image.clearAnimation();
            v.reset();
            image.layout(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());                
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }
        public void onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }

    });

    image.startAnimation(animation);
}

public void animateToRight () {     
    translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, width - image.getWidth() - fromXDelta , 0, 0);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image.clearAnimation();
            v.reset();
            image.layout(width - image.getWidth(), 0, width, image.getHeight());                
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }
        public void onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }

    });

    image.startAnimation(animation);
}

public void animateToEx (int control) {     

    if(control == 0) {
        // left to ex point
        translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, width - image.getWidth() - fromXDelta , 0, 0);
    } else if(control == 2) {
        // right to ex point
        translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, width - image.getWidth() - fromXDelta , 0, 0);
    }

    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image.clearAnimation();
            v.reset();
            image.layout(width - image.getWidth(), 0, width, image.getHeight());                
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }
        public void onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation arg0) { }

    });

    image.startAnimation(animation);
}

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you are doing it right... you need to read the documentation of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and its `life cycle`. the constructor you define is never gonna call... use `onCreate` instead of your constructor...

Comment: I've written those lines in onCreate method and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that method is deprecated, try to use this instead

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using getSystemService()?

```
getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```